# Django: Auto generate ID when form loads in a read only field

Tags: django, ajax

I want to generate a unique code base on month, year and number sequence for each transaction. Example 052101
Where 05 is the month, 21 is the year, and 01 is the count of number. The next code will be 052102 in that order. l want the generated code as value in a read only field when the form loads.

Comment: If you're not going to save this value anyway, you can just add it in your template.

Comment: I will save it after filling other fields on the form.

Comment: You can add the value to that field in the view of the form. That also prevents users from changing the value. In your template you can just use {% now "my" %} for the date

Comment: @Vincent: I don't want just date. I want to generate a transactional id anytime the form load. The format should be month, year and number sequence. Example 052101 where 05 is the month of May,  21 is the year 2021 and 01 is first id generated for May 2021. So the next id will be 052102, 052103 in that order. the month of June will be 062101, 062102 etc.

Comment: You can do that with the templatetag i commented before.